# Origine del detto "In guerra o in carestia ogni buco è galleria"

Tags: meaning, proverbs

Ho sentito più volte colleghi e amici fare riferimento a questo detto in situazioni in cui bisogna fare buon viso a cattivo gioco.

Ho anche trovato in rete alcune varianti con trincea al posto di buco (ed altre ancora più colorite) ma non sono riuscito a trovare una fonte che possa chiarire da dove deriva questo modo di dire.

Qualcuno di voi sa per caso spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4):

Da me è molto diffusa la versione "ogni buco è trincea", spesso usata per definire situazioni in cui un uomo va a letto con una donna molto più brutta di lui.

Immagino che la fonte risalga appunto ai tempi della prima Guerra Mondiale, una guerra di trincea, dove bisognava approfittare di ogni riparo per evitare di essere ammazzati dall'artiglieria nemica. La sfumatura "sessuale" penso sia nata in tempi più moderni.